# Dimensionar <td> usando bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tem como eu criar uma tabela com Bootstrap e fixar o tamanho de cada `<td>`? Gostaria de poder flexibilizar o tamanho das células de uma tabela com Bootstrap, é possível?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para tabelas você pode utilizar o mesmo padrão da divisão de `div`.

```
<tr class='row'>
    <td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">col 1</td>
    <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">col 2</td>
    <td class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">col 3</td>
</tr>
```

Veja [Grid Options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) para entender melhor a divisão de grids

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RK4dG/)**

Comment: Minha dificuldade é entender o sm, md, xs e lg. Ainda não consegui entender esses caras.

Comment: @pnet veja este link http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-html-css-javascript/bootstrap-e-formularios-html5/#11-14-grid-responsivo-do-bootstrap", talvez ajude você entender a divisão de grids, procure na página por: 11.14 - Grid responsivo do Bootstrap

Comment: @pnet, o sm, md, xs e lg tem a ver com o tamanho da tela do usuário, onde resumidamente sm = tela pequena, md = media, xs = super pequena, lg = grande (veja aqui com mais detalhes: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options ). Utilizando essas classes você controla como o conteúdo aparece em cada tamanho de tela. Lembrando que 100% da largura de uma row são 12 colunas, este exemplo `<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"> </div>` -> vai ocupar as 12 colunas [100%] em uma tela pequena (xs) e 6 colunas [50%] em uma tela média (md).